# Getting particular view from expandable listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, expandablelistview

In my list view I have an textview in expandable group and I want to open the dialog when textview is clicked to fill the information through edittext and update textview.

Problem: how could I get the groupview textview item in my fragment oncreateview() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass your view item form a fragment to an other. You should retrieve the object associated with your group view, pass this object to your second/edition fragment. You can use
setTargetFragment(...) and onActivityResult(...) to send the modified text from your second to your first fragment. And then you can update you list of object and refresh your expandableListView to display the updated text.

If you need help doing this please post your code.